How can I stop the noise from updating its position when I adjust the spline?
I gave this curve some displacement with the Noise Texture node. Now that I want to adjust the shape of the splines, how can I stop the noise from updating its position? Is this possible without applying the modifier?


I am not sure it is an update of the Noise Texture node. I think the update is about the tangent and normal used to define the direction of the position offset. These are modified when the control points are edited. What would you like to keep "unchanged" when adjusting the spline ? One approach could be to generate the "noise" for an auxiliary steady curve (e.g. a Star) and to transfer it to the "dynamic" spline.

Oh, you could use a 1D noise and pass index or factor or length as the input, that could work too

After you apply your modifier you no longer will be able to so easily edit your curve.
You need to somehow store the starting positions or calculated noise displacements before you modified a curve. You could do it this way:

Add shape keys: Basis and Key 1
Set the weight of the 2nd shape key Key 1 to 1.0 (full influence)
Keyframe the Key 1 toggle to be disabled on frame 1 and enabled elsewhere (disable it, go to frame 1, hover mouse over the toggle, press I, go to frame 2, enable it, with mouse still over, I)
use a node tree with a simulation which stores the first frame:




Alternatively you could just duplicate the curve and sample by index from the duplicate...
